# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /functions.php on line 192

Tags: php, wordpress

I have, since last morning, the following error showing up on my website hosted through godaddy.com with WP 3.2.1. I now know that the site was hacked. I don't have access to the WP admin CP since it also comes with the same error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/xx/xxxxx/html/websites/xxxxxxxx/wp-includes/functions.php on line 192

And this is the line of code in the php file:

```
$mm = substr( $mysqlstring, 8, 2 ); // Mysql string Month
```

Any one can help?

this is the whole block:

```
function size_format( $bytes, $decimals = 0 ) {
$quant = array(
    // ========================= Origin ====
    'TB' => 1099511627776,  // pow( 1024, 4)
    'GB' => 1073741824,     // pow( 1024, 3)
    'MB' => 1048576,        // pow( 1024, 2)
    'kB' => 1024,           // pow( 1024, 1)
    'B ' => 1,              // pow( 1024, 0)
);
foreach ( $quant as $unit => $mag )
    if ( doubl// Mysql string Year
$mm = substr( $mysqlstring, 8, 2 ); // Mysql string Month
$md = substr( $mysqlstring, 5, 2 ); // Mysql string day
$day = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $md, $mm, $my ); // The timestamp for mysqlstring day.
$weekday = date( 'w', $day ); // The day of the week from the timestamp
if ( !is_numeric($start_of_week) )
    $start_of_week = get_option( 'start_of_week' );

if ( $weekday < $start_of_week )
    $weekday += 7;

$start = $day - 86400 * ( $weekday - $start_of_week ); // The most recent week start day on or before $day
$end = $start + 604799; // $start + 7 days - 1 second
return compact( 'start', 'end' );
}

/**
 * Unserialize value only if it was serialized.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param string $original Maybe unserialized original, if is needed.
 * @return mixed Unserialized data can be any type.
 */
function maybe_unserialize( $original ) {
    if ( is_serialized( $original ) ) // don't attempt to unserialize data that wasn't serialized going in
        return @unserialize( $original );
    return $original;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code--a few lines before and after this one? Why do you think your site's been hacked?

Comment: In my experience the error often has to do with a line missing a semi-colon `;`.

Comment: Answer is simple: restore whole WP installation from backup.

Comment: Thank you for posting the complete function body.  The syntax error is pretty obvious.  Check out the two lines before the one that's flagged as an error. It's an incomplete statement.  As stated here in the comments, your best bet is restoring the file from backup.  That said, if the site *has* been hacked, you want to restore the *entire* site from backup, deleting everything first.

Comment: I had this exact same issue with a GoDaddy WP install on a site that I haven't touched in months.  Wish the mods didn't close this topic down.  Very confused what could have occurred that caused this.  I compared it to an older version of functions.php that I had from a prior install and fixed the size_format function to resolve my issue.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

The line before is:

```
if ( doubl// Mysql string Year
```

Obviously, the line is not complete, hence the parse error.